# Monitoring R data loading progress when using read.table

Tags: r, progress-bar, read.table

I've found a lot of answers for other types of data loading, but none for showing progress when R is reading data using `read.table(...)`. I've got a simple command:

```
data = read.table(file=filename,
                sep="\t",
                col.names=c("time","id","x","y"),
                colClasses=c("integer","NULL","NULL","NULL"))
```

This loads a large amount of data in about 30 seconds or so, but a progress bar would be really nice :-D

Comment: I think it will be very difficult to do this without deep hacking of `read.table`.  It's not even clear which component of `read.table` is the slow part ... I would `debug()` read.table [or use R profiling], figure out which component it was, and try to embed calls to `txtProgressBar` therein (hoping that the slow part did not drop down into C code ...)

Comment: It's not worth it if it's fairly complicated and gonna take more than ten minutes. I kind of assumed there was an easy way to have R 1) count the lines in a file, and 2) update a progress bar every time it read a line

Comment: but maybe `scan` with `what=list(integer(), NULL, NULL, NULL)` is (a lot) faster?

Answer (score 2):

Continuing experiments:

Construct a temporary working file:

```
n <- 1e7
dd <- data.frame(time=1:n,id=rep("a",n),x=1:n,y=1:n)
fn <- tempfile()
write.table(dd,file=fn,sep="\t",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```

Run 10 replications with `read.table` (with and without `colClasses` specified) and `scan`:

**edit**: corrected `scan` call in response to comment, updated results:

```
library(rbenchmark)
(b1 <- benchmark(read.table(fn,
                     col.names=c("time","id","x","y"),
                            colClasses=c("integer",
                              "NULL","NULL","NULL")),
                 read.table(fn,
                            col.names=c("time","id","x","y")),
          scan(fn,
               what=list(integer(),NULL,NULL,NULL)),replications=10))
```

**Results:**

```
2 read.table(fn, col.names = c("time", "id", "x", "y"))
1 read.table(fn, col.names = c("time", "id", "x", "y"), 
      colClasses = c("integer", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"))
3  scan(fn, what = list(integer(), NULL, NULL, NULL))

  replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self 
2           10 278.064 1.857016   232.786   30.722    
1           10 149.737 1.011801   141.365    2.388  
3           10 143.118 1.000000   140.617    2.105
```

(warning, these values are slightly cooked/inconsistent because I re-ran the benchmark and merged the results ... but the qualitative result should be OK).

`read.table` without `colClasses` is slowest (that's not surprising), but only (?) about 85% slower than `scan` for this example.  `scan` is only a tiny bit faster than `read.table` with `colClasses` specified.

With either `scan` or `read.table` one could write a "chunked" version that used the `skip` and `nrows` (`read.table`) or `n` (`scan`) parameters to read bits of the file at a time, then paste them together at the end.  I don't know how much this would slow the process down, but it would allow calls to `txtProgressBar` between chunks ...

Comment: `scan` wants `list(integer(), NULL, NULL, NULL)` rather than quoted characters (it'll read in four character vectors otherwise).

Comment: Actually, the chunked version is `fl = file(fn, "r"); while (length(r <- scan(fl, what, nmax)[[1]])) { }` with e.g., nmax=400000. Put the progress bar in `{}`.

Comment: PS.  I spent longer than I should have putting this sort of chunking around the `scan` call in a hacked copy of `read.table`.  Then I realized that there's a problem adding the progress bar, which is that we don't know in advance how long the file is!  This could be figured out fairly quickly in a Unix-like environment with a quick call to `wc`, but it all starts to seem a bit much ...